# Interrupt a postdelayed from a handler inside a OnCompletionListener

Tags: android, handler, android-mediaplayer, postdelayed

I have several different Activitys each with a MediaPlayer and a OnCompletionListener to start other activities after the current file has stopped playing. There also is a delay built in the OnCompletion Listener which i achieve through a Handler with postDelayed and it looks like this:

```
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Intent stopplay;
                    stopplay = new Intent(actualActivity, Class
                            .forName(nextView));
                    actualActivity.startActivity(stopplay);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, stopTime);


}
```

The problem with this is, when i call my SettingsActivity, sometimes it just switches to the Activity that would have come next. So i assume it's hanging in the postDelayd's wait...

How could i get around this?

I also do this in the onStop, onPause and onDestroy of these Activities:

```
if (mPlayer != null) {
        mPlayer.stop();
        mPlayer.release();
        mPlayer = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to cancel your handler's callback when you don't want it to be executed.

Define your handler at your activity scope(because you have to reach it). Something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable myRunnable;
        ...
}
```

and define your runnable inside your activity(maybe inside you `onCreate` method)

```
myRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Intent stopplay;
            stopplay = new Intent(actualActivity, Class
                    .forName(nextView));
            actualActivity.startActivity(stopplay);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

Change your code:

```
handler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
handler.postDelayed(myRunnable, stopTime);
```

And if you want to cancel it try this:

```
handler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the handler is use now is inside a class that extends the OnCompletionListener.

it looks like this:

http://pastebin.com/fGJeSs0y

Comment: You have to have a reference to that handler.

Comment: Do you see where my problem is? I can't pass that handler to the OnCompletionListener...

Comment: Ok, you can write a public method into subclass of OnCompletionListener to removeCallbacks of handler. And call that method from where you created your OnCompletionListener's subclass's instance. That shouldn't be difficult.

Comment: Solved it! Thanks for your help!